# Why i am getting gyp error while downloading node-pty on windows 11

Tags: python, node.js, windows, visual-studio-code, node-pty

This is the error i get when i run npm i node-pty

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Vojas Gonnade\OneDrive\Desktop\Project 2 - AI terminal\terminal-ai\node_modules\node-pty
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.10.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.0 found at "C:\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2015 as it is only supported up to Node.js 18
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Vojas Gonnade\OneDrive\Desktop\Project 2 - AI terminal\terminal-ai\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Vojas Gonnade\OneDrive\Desktop\Project 2 - AI terminal\terminal-ai\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Vojas Gonnade\OneDrive\Desktop\Project 2 - AI terminal\terminal-ai\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:369:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Vojas Gonnade\OneDrive\Desktop\Project 2 - AI terminal\terminal-ai\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2015 (C:\Users\Vojas Gonnade\OneDrive\Desktop\Project 2 - AI terminal\terminal-ai\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:353:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Vojas Gonnade\OneDrive\Desktop\Project 2 - AI terminal\terminal-ai\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:67:12
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at failPowershell (C:\Users\Vojas Gonnade\OneDrive\Desktop\Project 2 - AI terminal\terminal-ai\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:156:7)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.parseData (C:\Users\Vojas Gonnade\OneDrive\Desktop\Project 2 - AI terminal\terminal-ai\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:170:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Vojas Gonnade\OneDrive\Desktop\Project 2 - AI terminal\terminal-ai\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:143:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:414:7)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22631
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Vojas Gonnade\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Project 2 - AI terminal\\terminal-ai\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Vojas Gonnade\OneDrive\Desktop\Project 2 - AI terminal\terminal-ai\node_modules\node-pty
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.10.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Vojas Gonnade\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-14T14_17_48_227Z-debug-0.log
```

Not getting the expected result.

Comment: It's telling you it can't find msvc, but you didn't include any details about addressing that.

Answer (score 0):

`node-gyp` requires a **C++** compiler to function.

You could try the following steps:

1. Install [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).
2. Install the **C++ Workload**: During the Visual Studio installation, make sure to select the **Desktop development with C++ workload**.